# IE8 & 9 Html Rendering Issues

Tags: html, iframe, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-9, sharepoint-2013

We have a web part for SharePoint 2013 which renders a video in Iframe and after Iframe there is a textbox with button to comment on it. It is working fine with IE 10 and IE 11, but in IE8 and IE9, it does not render any html after the Iframe. Also in inspect element it does not show any html for textbox button.

In page source of current page it shows html is there for text box and button.

Html for web part is like :

```
<iframe width="500" height="250" src="/_layouts/15/videoembedplayer.aspx?extSrc=http://myurl/siteassets/video.mp4" data-duration="0">iframe not supported</iframe>
<br/><br/>
<div>
<fieldset>
<legend></legend>
<input type="text" id="comment" />
<input type="submit" value="Comment" />
</fieldset>
</div>
```

I have check the css also, no css is hiding it.

Thank You

Comment: So it also does not work with the changes to your html you just made?

Comment: Yes.. not working still

Answer (score 1):

You HTML is invalid. You missed a quote from one of your attribute values. This is probably causing some browsers to see the end tag for the iframe as part of the start tag and thus everything that follows it as being part of the alternative content for non-iframe supporting browsers.

Use [a validator](http://validator.w3.org/nu/).

Comment: Or just look at the colours here at SO

Comment: It was by mistake, the quote are there and it is still not visible